# PHP function: Is this bad form or properly done?

Tags: php, function

I have written a long script that does exactly what I need, but now I am find out the usefulness of functions so I can use them in other scripts.

My script works perfectly the way I originally wrote it, and also works perfectly with the way I implemented the function I created.

As I am brand new to writing functions and I have never seen one implemented the way I have done, I don't know if it is good form or not.

#### Original Way

```
foreach($get_prefixes as $prefix) {
    if($prefix['type'] == 'pre') {
        $sql  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$prefix[table]` LIKE 'sku_%' ";
        $sku_cols = $objDb->query($sql);
        foreach($sku_cols as $col) {
            echo $col['Field'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

And then there is the way I did it with the created function. Again it works perfectly, but is there is a "proper" way to do this?

```
function getSku_($table) {
    global $objDb;
    $sql  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table` LIKE 'sku_%' ";
    $sku_cols = $objDb->query($sql);
    return $sku_cols;
}

foreach($get_prefixes as $prefix) {
    if($prefix['type'] == 'pre') {
        foreach(getSku_($prefix['table']) as $col) {
            echo $col['Field'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd opt for not using an underscore in the end of the function name. I won't break anything, it just isn't common and looks a bit strange.

Comment: I would perhaps pass in the `$objDb` as a function argument rather than define it as global but that could just be personal preference over functionality.

Comment: It's more than just fine. What you did is called refactoring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring . And, per a friend of mine, that's the second best to "good factoring" ;).

Comment: In general, asking PHP coders what is good and bad form is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks everyone for your great ideas. I am essentially self-teaching(learning I should say) and php fascinates me. So what I am doing is going over all of the script i have written and saying to myself, how can I reduce the amount of code written and how can i simply the whole process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the function, except for its `naming`. It's not incorrect, just that I understand its convention is to follow naming as `abc_pqr` or `abcPqr` or `_abcPqr (for private functions)`.

**Edit:** I also don't see `$get_prefixes` defined anywhere, before using in the foreach, in the function. Where is it coming from?

```
foreach($get_prefixes as $prefix) { //This line
```

If the functions differ in just the query, `"sku"` and `"sku "` then you don't even need two functions, just use an `OR` in the query (preferred) or maybe two queries, if you want the two result sets to be separate.

Comment: thanks for the replies. the reason for the underscore is that I will have two functions:
getSku
getSku_

and one finds columns that begin with "sku" and the other finds columns that begin with "sku_"

so i figured that would be the easiest way to know the difference between the two funcitons

Comment: In that case, you should probably refactor that out to be another parameter. You could also pass in `$objDb` to avoid the nasty global too. How about `showColumns($objDb, $table, 'sku_');`?

Comment: then probably name it something like `getSku_1` or `getSku1` and `getSku_2` or `getSku2`. These are naming conventions, for better readability and varies across companies/organisations. If you're the sole person handling the code, maybe its ok :) (though with time and experience, I bet you will not prefer it urself ;))

Comment: In that case, you could have one function "getSku", and pass it an optional prefix as a parameter.

Comment: ... or figure out the semantics behind the column naming and make it explicit, something like, off the top of my head, getApprovedSku.

Comment: if the functions differ in just the query, `sku` and `sku ` then you dont even need 2 functions, just use an `OR` in the query (preferred) or maybe 2 queries, if you want the 2 resultsets to be separate.

Comment: coder, get_prefixes is defined much further up in the code. its just a query on the db that fetches data from a table.

Comment: cool, and good luck learning/coding :)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the crowd of the enlightened! This first step you took in a right direction is a very significant one!

Your function is right, and it is written as it should be written.

May the force be with you on your further journey towards reusable, clean and modular coding! (wish more people would recognize the importance of these things.)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with it. You have separated out the functionality which fetches the information from the database, and you use it within your code via a function. It seems fine to me. In this way you can call the function from anywhere in your code, and you are not limited to only using it in the loop.

EDIT: I agree with the previous answer, that the underscore in the function name is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, except for some naming oddities but you are new so that is understandable. You might want to take a look at something like [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) as well to reduce the two foreach() calls you have.

Answer (score 3):

It looks good, but as a point to consider, can '$get__prefixes' ever be NULL? If so, consider checking for that posibility as well with an 'if()' prior the the 'foreach' such as:

```
if ($get_prefixes != NULL) {
    foreach($get_prefixes as $prefix) { 
        ....
    }
}
```

This could prevent a potential error.

Answer (score 3):

**I would write it like this:**

```
// Add code here...
function getSku($table) {
    global $objDb;
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table} LIKE 'sku_%';"; // Here be changes
    $sku_cols = $objDb->query($sql);  
    return $sku_cols;
}
```

**Why?** You original version does not cater for direct DB access like this: getSku("schema.table"); So I removed you ` wrapper and enclosed the string. Now just feed the wrapper like this:

```
getSku('`table`'); // or
getSku('`schema`.`table`'); // or
getSku('table'); // or
getSku('schema.table');
```

It's of more general use and that's what functions are for.